# Re-raise/-throw an error

Tags: error-handling, progress-4gl, openedge

I want to "re-raise" an error after a `NO-ERROR` statement like this:

```
FIND FIRST table
    WHERE table.ID = myID
    EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-WAIT NO-ERROR.

IF (NOT AVAILABLE temp AND LOCKED temp) THEN
    /* Here I want to raise/throw the last error ("Raise ERROR:STATUS") */

IF (NOT AVAILABLE table) THEN
    CREATE table.
```

Is there such a statement in Progress?

Comment: Which is your OpenEdge release?

Comment: It's OpenEdge Version 10.2B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenEdge 10.1C and beyond you can THROW errors. To re-THROW an error, you must CATCH it first.

So either,

```
IF (NOT AVAILABLE temp AND LOCKED temp) THEN
    UNDO, THROW NEW Progress.Lang.AppError 
         (ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE (1), 
          ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE-NUM (1)) .
```

or you CATCH the error in the first place:

```
DO ON ERROR UNDO, THROW: /* ABL try */
    FIND FIRST table
        WHERE table.ID = myID
        EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-WAIT .

    CATCH err AS Progress.Lang.SysError:
        IF LOCKED temp THEN
             UNDO, THROW err . /* re-THROW */
    END CATCH .
END . /* ABL try block */

IF (NOT AVAILABLE table) THEN
    CREATE table.
```

Comment: Will the error be thrown even when you use the `NO-ERROR` statement?

Comment: No. The NO-ERROR should not be there.

Answer (score 3):

Mike's response is correct. But just to offer earlier release solutions, since this is permanent record: previously to catch being available, the correct would be to RETURN ERROR to the caller procedure. ERROR-STATUS does not get cleared until NO-ERROR is used again, and you'll still be able to query the error messages available.